# Best practices to organize the automated tests in a continuous delivery world

Tags: test-management, test-automation-framework, continuous-integration, source-control

I am trying to organize my automated tests in the source control [ GIT] - mostly Jprofiler/Jmeter, Selenium and SOAP tests.

What are the industry standards for organizing/managing the Automated Tests in a continuous delivery environment? I am planning to Mavenize the tests and organization but I am trying to find better approaches/ industry standards. Are there any articles/blogs which I can refer regarding the test management.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.  Are you asking a source control (Git) question, or a build (Maven) question, or something else?

Comment: Are you looking for a standard like CMMI or a methodology as Agile?

Comment: You're looking for approaches better than Maven. Why Maven is not not enough?

Answer (score 1):

Most shops I know keep the tests in the same codebase as the programs and so under the same source code control mechanisms.
The tests are run when code is pushed (both master and branches for developers).
Please be more specific about what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using cucumber to organize your tests?  Or just using a unit test framework like JUnit?  My automation is in C# stack, and we use specflow to organize our tests which is pretty nice.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid any 'industry best-practices' in approaching how you organise your tests.

It's hard to advise without knowing what your development context is, but I would look at what parts of the application my tests are checking and then attempt to merge those tests into the same repository as the code that's being checked.

So for example if you have a bunch of SOAP tests I would assume (maybe incorrectly) that they are testing a web service so I would group those tests with the repository for that web service.  You could then bake the running of those specific tests within Maven build.